# Continuity and sequences problem

Tags: analysis

Question:

Suppose $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a function satisfying:
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = -\infty $

part a) Show that if $(x_n)$ is any sequence of real numbers such that the sequence $(f(x_n))$ either converges to a real number or diverges to $+\infty$, then $(x_n)$ is bounded.

my attempt of a solution of part a)
I instead went to prove the contrapositive, i.e. if we have some sequence $(x_n)$ which is not bounded, this implies that $(f(x_n))$ does not converge to some real number and $(f(x_n))$ does not converge to infinity, i.e. $f(x_n) \rightarrow -\infty$

so if $(x_n)$ is unbounded then $|x_n| > H $ for some real H. The definition of $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = -\infty$: $\forall P\in\mathbb{R}$ $\exists q \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $ x>q \Rightarrow |f(x)|<P$ since $|x_n| > H$ then for some real number P $\exists H \in \mathbb{R} $ s.t. $x_n > H \Rightarrow |f(x)| < P$ so $\lim_{x_n \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = -\infty$

I'm assuming the above is incorrect as I had to force the result, any attempt on solving the above would be great.

I also have a part b) which I've attempted - would it better to start a new thread of post it here?

edit: in response to the top answer (proving it directly)

How did you get that $f(x_n)$ is bounded below?

Anyway, following from this, $ x < A \Rightarrow f(x) < M$ and $x > B \Rightarrow f(x) < M$ so $A < x < B \Rightarrow f(x) < M$ not sure how to link this to x_n. Are the M's in $f(x_n) \geq M$ and $f(x) < M$ in your answer supposed to be the same? If so, why?

Comment: $f(x_n)\to-\infty$ does not follow from your assumptions; but it will be true for some *subsequence*.

Comment: It would be better to make (b) a separate question, especially since the answers to this one might give you some ideas for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is direct: It follows from the assumptions that $f(x_n)$ is bounded below, i.e., there is some $M$ so that $f(x_n)\ge M$ for all $n$.

But also it follows from the assumptions that there are numbers $A$ and $B$ so that $f(x)<M$ if either $x<A$ or $x>B$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: How did you get that $f(x_n)$ is bounded below?

Anyway, following from this, $ x < A \Rightarrow f(x) < M$ and $x > B \Rightarrow f(x) < M$ so $A < x < B \Rightarrow f(x) < M$ not sure how to link this to x_n. Are the M's in $f(x_n) \geq M$ and $f(x) < M$ in your answer supposed to be the same? If so, why?

Comment: A sequence that converges to a real number, or diverges to $+\infty$, is bounded below. You cannot conclude $f(x)<M$ from $A<x<B$, though – that is getting the logic backwards. Yes, the $M$'s are the same. You *first* pick it as a lower bound for $f(x_n)$, and *then* use it to determine $A$ and $B$. Since $f(x_n)\ge M$ you cannot have $x_n<A$ or $x_n>B$, since that would imply $f(x_n)<M$. So in the end you have $A\le x_n\le B$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

For part a) the contrapositive seems like a workable approach. However, the claim that $\{x_n\}$ does not remain bounded, does not imply that it diverges. For example $$x_n = \begin{cases} 1 & n \text{ is even} \\ n & n \text{ is odd} \end{cases}$$ is not bounded, but does not "diverge to $\pm \infty$" either. What you can conclude, though, is that there is a subsequence which diverges to $\pm \infty$. In that case, if $\{x_{n_k}\}$ is such a subsequence, you'll notice that $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = -\infty$. Therefore if $\{f(x_n)\}$ has a limit, it must be $-\infty$, which will conclude the contrapositive argument.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive approach works fine, but you’ve gone astray a bit with it. For instance, the hypothesis that the sequence is unbounded doesn’t mean that $|x_n|>H$ for some real $H$: it means that for each $H>0$ there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n|\ge H$. Here’s an outline of how the argument might be carried out legitimately.

If $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is unbounded, there are $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n|\ge 1$; let $n_1$ be the smallest of these subscripts. There are also $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n|\ge 2$; let $n_2$ be the smallest of these subscripts. In general, let $n_k$ be the smallest $n$ such that $|x_{n_k}|\ge k$. It’s not hard to see that $n_1\le n_2\le n_3\le\ldots.$

- Show that $\langle n_k:k\ge 1\rangle$ has a **strictly** increasing subsequence, so that without loss of generality we may assume that $n_1<n_2<n_3<\ldots$.

Now let $P=\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:x_{n_k}>0\}$ and $N=\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:x_{n_k}<0\}$; at least one of $P$ and $N$ must be infinite.

- Show that if $P$ is infinite, then $\langle f(x_{n_k}):k\in P\rangle$ converges to $-\infty$, and if $N$ is infinite, then $\langle f(x_{n_k}):k\in N\rangle$ converges to $-\infty$.

In either case $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a subsequence converging to $-\infty$, so ...

---

The intuition behind this is much more straightforward than the slightly messy details. The idea is that if $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is unbounded, it must have a subsequence that converges to $\infty$ or a subsequence that converges to $-\infty$, and in either case $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has a subsequence that converges to $-\infty$. The messy detail work is in showing that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ really does have a subsequence as claimed.